# 'Expires' Column in Announcement Content Type Cannot Reference Another Column for Calculated Value

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns, calculated-field

The 'Expires' property (metadata) for the Announcement item content type for the OOTB Announcements app (list) is a datetime data type.

The setting of the default value on new item creation can be '(None)', 'Todays date', a specific date/time value, and a calculated value.

I entered the formula `=[Created] + 2` believing that it would add 2 days to whatever the value of the Created column and set the value. An error arose that the calculated value referenced other fields in the list.

It's true that it is a datetime column data type and not a calculated column data type, where field references are permitted. But the Expires site column must be used to indicate when the item is to be deleted. And to what purpose of usefulness would it be to have a datetime data type column that offers the option of a 'Calculated Value' for the default type?

Anyway, the workaround is apparently to use a function (like `TODAY()`) and not a reference to another field. Thus `TODAY() + 2` works.

If someone has an explanation, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

I could also reproduce this situation on my end. It seems to be by default we cannot refer to other fields in the formula of Calculated value in a date and time column. Unfortunately I cannot find any official documentation explains this. You can go to [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/m365) to share your user voice.